# Integral with complex parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can I obtain an analytic expression for the following integral?

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\nu \, \frac{e^{-\frac{(\nu -iX)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{1+ \frac{\nu^2}{\sigma^4}}$$

Here $\sigma>0$, and $X \in \mathbb{C}$.

I tried using the below command but it returned the same expression. Any help will be great in this regard.

```
Integrate[E^(-(ν - I X)^2/(2 σ^2))/(ν^2/σ^4 + 1), {ν,-∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> σ > 0]
```

Comment: I think no chance for an analytical expression of that integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{(\nu -i X)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\frac{\nu ^2}{\sigma ^4}+1} \, d\nu =-\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{\left(X-\sigma ^2\right)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \pi  \sigma ^2
   \left(-2+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{X-\sigma ^2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)-e^{2 X} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{X+\sigma ^2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)$$

```
 N[With[{X = 3 + 4 I, \[Sigma] = 3}, -(1/2) E^((X - \[Sigma]^2)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)) \[Pi] \[Sigma]^2 (-2 + 
 Erfc[(X - \[Sigma]^2)/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])] - 
 E^(2 X) Erfc[(X + \[Sigma]^2)/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])])], 30]

 (*6.29144555383952196652073437413 + 1.23139881428285232437943972824 I*)

 With[{X = 3 + 4 I, \[Sigma] = 3}, NIntegrate[
 E^(-(\[Nu] - I X)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))/(\[Nu]^2/\[Sigma]^4 + 
 1), {\[Nu], -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 31]]

 (*6.291445553839521966520734374127 + 1.231398814282852324379439728238 I*)
```

I use **FourierTransform** to solve this integral:

```
 FourierTransform[(Exp[-(x^2/(2 \[Omega]^2)) + X^2/(
 2 \[Omega]^2)]*\[Omega]^4)/(\[Omega]^4 + x^2), x, W, 
 Assumptions -> {\[Omega] > 0}] /. W ->  X/\[Omega]^2
 (* ? *)
```

I waited half an hour and got no response, so I used **Maple 2023** and got a response in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `FourierTransform[(Exp[-(x^2/(2 \[Omega]^2)) + X^2/(
 2 \[Omega]^2)]*\[Omega]^4)/(\[Omega]^4 + x^2), x, W, 
 Assumptions -> {\[Omega] > 0}] /. W ->  X/\[Omega]^2` returns the input in 13.2 on Windows 10 in several hours.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for solving.

Answer (score 0):

If the term I X is meant to be imaginary I * Complex, then the answer is not definitely true. Make the formal substitution

```
Together /@ 
 Inactive[Integrate][ 
   dx E^(-(x - I X)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))/(x^2/\[Sigma]^4 + 1),
       {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] /. 
     {x -> I X + \[Sigma] y , dx -> \[Sigma] dy } // FullSimplify

  Inactive[Integrate][
   (dy E^(-(y^2/2)) \[Sigma]^5)/
       (\[Sigma]^4+(I X+y \[Sigma])^2),  -oo<  X+y \[Sigma] < oo]



 ConditionalExpression[
(1/2)*dy* E^((X - \[Sigma]^2)^2/
   (2*\[Sigma]^2))*\[Sigma]^2* (Pi*Erf[(X - \[Sigma]^2)/
   (Sqrt[2]*\[Sigma])] - E^(2*X)*Pi*Erf[(X + \[Sigma]^2)/(Sqrt[2]*[Sigma])] 
   +  I*(Log[(I*\[Sigma])/(X - \[Sigma]^2)] - Log[(I*\[Sigma])/
     (-X +\[Sigma]^2)] + E^(2*X)*(Log[-((I*\[Sigma])/
     (X + \[Sigma]^2))] - Log[(I*\[Sigma])/(X + \[Sigma]^2)]))),  
        Re[X/\[Sigma]] != Re[\[Sigma]] && Re[X/\[Sigma] + \[Sigma]] != 0]
```

Since by inspection, the integrand has a singularity at the zeros of the denominator, the shifting of the path $x \rightarrow i X + \sigma y$, may change the integral. A simple check is the numerical integral over the interval of confidence for a Gaussian x by +-3 sigma

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for the answer. To clarify, I X in your case is I * Real, is it?
Also just wondering, why is there a $dy$ in the final conditional expression, which presumably is your answer for the integral?

Comment: I take Leibniz differentials ds, dy  dy/dx always for fast, error free,  substitutions. They finally always evaluate to 1.,

Comment: @MichaelWilliams Roland's answer does seem to agree with numerical `NIntegrate` when you set $dy$ to 1. I tried `With[{X = 3 + 4 I, \[Sigma] = 3},
 NIntegrate[
  E^(-(\[Nu] - I X)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))/(\[Nu]^2/\[Sigma]^4 + 
     1), {\[Nu], -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]` for example, and got `6.29145 + 1.2314 I` though I don't understand the method here.

Comment: A change of  a variable in an improper integral is not so simple. This should be grounded in every case. That we see is empty talk.

Comment: The change of a variable in a Fourier transform like integral is always an inspection of singularities and evaluation of residues or something worse for closed loop integrals on paths through the jungle. Because today nobody  is teaching or learning this art, there are tables from the golden years of  applied complex analysis. Before CAS times,the table users mostly had no idea whats wrong there. I remember a first statistical check in the 1990 found 15% errors. Fortunately,  errors remain over the years in the never asked part of the formula store only.